# accessing published mvc3 app in server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, webserver

I am trying to publish my asp.net mvc3 web application and this is my first time publishing. I've been able to publish the application in iis and it is working fine. But when i put the application in the server, other computers in the network cannot access the page.

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I am using windows 7, v4.0 framework.

My web.config as authentication set to forms and it uses asp.net membership.

UPDATE:

Just checked and it is working well in windows xp, IIS5. The client can access the application in the server.
The problem is only in windows 7, IIS7.

Again, the simple page with no authentication is working from windows 7, iis7 as well.

Comment: What version of IIS is the server running?

Comment: It looks like the most likely problem is that the user account that the web site is running under is not the default "web server" user, so the site is not configured to allow anonymous access.

Comment: problem with iis7 but working fine in iis5

Comment: i've enabled anonymous access and there is still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with the authentication of the Application Pool. Check that the user you're using to authenticate the accesses to your application in IIS has access to the site.